# Where to specify total number of coins that could be mined in the lifetime of mining. How to specify specific amount of coins to mined each year

Tags: mining

I am trying to create a new cryptocurrency based on ethereum. The challenge which I am facing is, where to specify a total number of tokens that would
be allowed for lifetime mining. And the number of coins that can be mined each year.

Comment: Ethereum doesn't have an explicit cap on total emission, or yearly emission. To have such features you have to modify the source code.